URL link is opening a blank page when clicked, but a populated page when "open in new tab" is used
Working on a internal web page at work.
Simple page, just a list of clickable links to our vendor's websites.
One link is producing an odd effect.
When you click the link, it opens a new tab with the correct URL, but the page is blank.
If you right-click and tell it to "open in new tab" it will open a new tab with that same URL, but will populate correctly.
Only the following link is having this issue.
<a href="https://portal.kmpbrand.com/US/portal/scripts/login.asp" target="new">

I've check this in Edge and Chrome, it behaves the same in both.
I see no difference in the formatting between this link and the others.

There exists no target="new". you need to use _blank.

Use _blank instead of new.
<a href="https://portal.kmpbrand.com/US/portal/scripts/login.asp" target="_blank">

There is no "new".
See this answer as well.
